# Negating part of a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build regex to find classes into python code without explicitly inheritance from `object`.

```
import re

test_string = '''
class Test(object):
    pass

class Test:
    pass
'''

regex = r'class .*(?!\(object\)).*'

re.compile(regex).findall(test_string)
```

Which gives me:

```
'class Test(object):', 'class Test:'
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7WjWCIlUeRsQU4CQ)

But I need only `'class Test:'`.

At the same time positive lookahead works fine:

```
>>> print regex = r'class .*(?=\(object\)).*'
['class Test(object):']
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Why would you use regex and not `ast`? Using regex is much more bug-prone.

Comment: @Bharel just gathering some statistics from github repos

Comment: @xi well, it is somewhat problematic, as you can't tell between `class test: ...` and `"class test: ..."`. Any data in comments, strings or docstrings will count too :-/

Comment: @Bharel good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `(?!.*\(object\))` negative lookahead after "class ":

```
class (?!.*\(object\)).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vG7tA5/1)

The `.*(?!\(object\)).*` subpattern matches any 0+ characters other than a newline that is not followed with `(object)`. It effectively grabs all the line up to its end, and does not find any `(object)` after it. The second `.*` does not even match anything as all the characters already "belong" to the first `.*`.

In `(?!.*\(object\))`, the check occurs after consuming `class`+space, and fails the match once there is an `(object)` somewhere further on the current line.